# No privileges on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm trying to follow a udemy course and in order to complete it I need to have proper working phpMyAdmin CP.

I am running through WAMP 2.4, I went to localhost/phpmyadmin and "logged in" (username is admin, password is blank") and went to complete the first step which is to create a database.

But I see a red x and "no priveleges" where I should see the database creation input.
I tried going back to the home of phpMyAdmin and changing my password to not be blank but I get an error message when I try that too.

```
Create database:
No Privileges
```

Comment: You will need to set database privileges for your user under the 'Privileges' tab in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

User you are connecting to phpmyadmin has no privileges set for it to be able to create database.

Edit [config File](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html) on phpmyadmin setup and set a user with more permissions root user for mysql can be good since this is for a course?

Comment: Generally this is bad practice. But as he said, if this is only for a course and they aren't grading you on security... go for it.

Answer (score 1):

The actual solution is to use the correct MySQL user account to login.

By default ALL MySQL installs come with ONE pre configured Userid and that is **root** it comes with no password.

So when phpMyAdmin asks you to login use :-

`Username = root
password = (leave this blank)`

Then press the Go button.

You should really now add a password to this account as it is the SUPER User account. Add the same password to **all 3** of the *root* user accounts. Yes all 3, there are rooot@localhost and root@127.0.0.1 and root@::1

Remember that a MySQL user account is domain specific, in other words you can create user1 that is allowed to login from a specific ip address or many specific ip address's